# Algorithm - the longest chord whose supporting line contains a given point, in a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, algorithms, convex-analysis

"Let $P$ be a convex $n$-gon and $q$ a point in the plane. Find an algorithm to compute the longest chord whose supporting line contains q."

When $q$ is external to $P$, I think I can prove the longest chord contains at least one vertex of $P$. And for each vertex $v$ the line segment $[qv]$ intersects $P$ at most once (without counting $v$ and eliminating the case where $[qv]$ is colinear with an edge of $P$).
An algorithm could be for each vertex to compute its distance with the potential intersection. $\mathcal{O} (n)$ for the loop on vertices, $\mathcal{O} (n\log n)$ to find the intersection with Bentley-Ottman. Overall running time: $\mathcal{O} (n^2\log n)$.

I am wondering if I cannot get a faster algorithm with finding the intersection in $\mathcal{O} (\log n)$, using the convexity to come up with a binary search.

When $q$ is inside of $P$, I am not even sure the chord we are looking for has to contain any vertices of $P$! So I do not even know how to discretize the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, although I find that [the quoted exercise is listed here](http://www-ma2.upc.es/vera/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/DAG-Pr1-2014-15.pdf) as Problem 10 for the current quarter.  Does the "supporting line" mean a supporting line of the convex polygon $P$?  Or does "supporting line" relate directly to "the longest chord"?  If the former, there would be two supporting lines of the polygon passing through $q$, but it leaves open how this is to be related to a longest chord.

Comment: Yes I happen to attend this class. The supporting line here is actually the line defined by the chord. It is not a supporting line of $P$. In the drawing below, the line defined by A and B is such a supportinng line containing $q$.

Answer (score 0):

The chord doesn't have to contain a vertex of $P$, as this example shows:
[image]

$AB$ is clearly longer than $CD$.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Okay now I don't even know how to start

Comment: But for an internal point $q$, the longest chord passing throught $q$ has to contain a vertex of $P$ no ?

Comment: @lafaillette: What makes you think that?

Comment: Well I admit this is not proved at all. I just could not find a counterexample.

Comment: I think you are correct on this point, but I don't see an obvious proof.